# what is direct binding in QML?

Tags: qt

I'm referencing https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html to study binding.
I can't understand the meaning of direct binding mentioned in the "Conditional Bindings" statement
Can you give me an example of what direct binding is?
Thanks.

Comment: That’d be the standard binding used in 99% of the cases: `Foo { bar: “Hello” }`, “Hello” being bound to the property “bar”.

Comment: Thanks Frank Osterfeld!. I now understand binding more.